# creating several custom carriers in Magento2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am kinda new in coding and super new in Magento. I have created a custom carrier following these instructions: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout-add-custom-carrier.html#create-configuration and it works like a charm.
Then, I tried to create one more custom carrier by duplicating and renaming my Vendor folder. I have also altered some stuff in the code:

in registration.php

```php
    <?php
    
    use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
    
    ComponentRegistrar::register(
        ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Vendor2_CustomShipping',
        __DIR__
    );

in composer.json

    {
        "name": "vendor2/custom-shipping",
        "description": "Custom shipping module",
        "require": {
            "php": "~7.2.0||~7.3.0",
            "magento/framework": "102.0.*",
            "magento/module-backend": "101.0.*",
            "magento/module-catalog": "103.0.*",
            "magento/module-config": "101.1.*",
            "magento/module-directory": "100.3.*",
            "magento/module-quote": "101.1.*",
            "magento/module-sales": "102.0.*",
            "magento/module-sales-rule": "101.1.*",
            "magento/module-shipping": "100.3.*",
            "magento/module-store": "101.0.*"
        },
        "type": "magento2-module",
        "license": [
            "OSL-3.0",
            "AFL-3.0"
        ],
        "autoload": {
            "files": [
                "registration.php"
            ],
            "psr-4": {
                "Vendor2\\CustomShipping\\": ""
            }
        },
        "version": "1.0.0"
    }
```

in module.xml:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Vendor2_CustomShipping" >
            <sequence>
                <module name="Magento_Store"/>
                <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
                <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
                <module name="Magento_SalesRule"/>
            </sequence>
        </module>
    </config>
```

in config.xml:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
        <default>
            <carriers>
                <customshipping>
                    <active>0</active>
                    <title>Custom Shipping Title</title>
                    <name>Custom Shipping Method Name</name>
                    <shipping_cost>10</shipping_cost>
                    <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
                    <sort_order>15</sort_order>
                    <model>Vendor2\CustomShipping\Model\Carrier\Customshipping</model>
                </customshipping>
            </carriers>
        </default>
    </config>
```

and in the Customshipping.php:

```
namespace Vendor2\CustomShipping\Model\Carrier;
```

I successfully enabled the new module and upgraded magento, but when I go to my admin I can see only one custom carrier option available. I also tried removing firstly created module and that makes the second one appear. My guess is that there is a conflict but I don't know how to resolve it.
thanks

Comment: Have you given the two carriers a different id? It should be unique both in the system and config xml's. ( <group id="customshipping", <customshipping> and so on). Besides that, since "you" are the vendor in this case I'd go for an approach in your namespace where the Vendor is unique and what's below it differs (two modules for two carriers). Also, if you weren't aware, you can add two carriers without the need to have two modules on their own, just populate those XML's properly within the <section id="carriers" and the <default> <carriers> with different models.

Comment: this worked, thanks a lot for your help. Also I went for simpler folder structure as you proposed, so I also changed namespace in Customshipping.php and model in config.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second shipping method is overwriting the first shipping method. To prevent this, some more changes are needed:

In etc/adminhtml/system.xml change `<group id="customshipping" ...>` to `<group id="customshipping2" ...>`.

Also in etc/config.xml change `<customshipping>` to `<customshipping2>`.

In Model/Carrier/Customshipping.php change `protected $_code = 'customshipping';` to `protected $_code = 'customshipping2';`.

With these changes, you should be able to see two new shipping methods in the Magento admin.